# How to print .grf file to zebra printer memory

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I have developed an application in C# which prints image to my zebra printer.

My zebra print is **Zebra printer 104S** version.
When ever i am printing the image to **my printer its takes a longer time to print the image and the image is starting from the little bit below of the label**.

What i am trying to ask is how can i send my converted GRF image to printer. Where **i need to print fast** and **i need to flush the memory of my zebra printer each time i print a new image**. How can i do this.

Code snippet:

```
private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = image_print() + Print_image();
    PrintFactory.sendTextToLPT1(s);
    /*string Filename = img_path.Text;
    MessageBox.Show("file", Filename);
    // if (Filename.ToCharArray().Intersect(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()).Any())
    //   return;
    File.Delete(Path.Combine(@"E:\Debug", Filename));*/
}

private string image_print()
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    string path = "";
    string full_path = "";
    string filename_noext = "";
    ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\ZTOOLS\FONTS";
    ofd.Filter = "GRF files (*.grf)|*.grf";
    ofd.FilterIndex = 2;
    ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filename_noext = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName);
        path = Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName);
        img_path.Text = filename_noext;
        //MessageBox.Show(filename_noext, "Filename");
        // MessageBox.Show(full_path, "path");
        //move file from location to debug
        string replacepath = @"E:\Debug";
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(replacepath, fileName);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename_noext))
            System.IO.File.Copy(path, newpath);

    }
    StreamReader test2 = new StreamReader(img_path.Text);
    string s = test2.ReadToEnd();
    return s;
}

private string Print_image()
{
    //^XA^WDE:*.GRF^FS^XZ
        string s = "";
        s += "^XA^LH" + "" + "," + "" + "^FO0,0^XGR" + img_path.Text + ".GRF,1,1^FS";
        s += "^FO184,155^A0N,47,36^FD" + "" + "^FS";
        s += "^FO250,235^AFN,33,0^FD" + "" + "^FS";
        s += "^FO500,561^A0N,24,19^FD" + "" + "^FS";
        s += "^XZ";
        return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the image to EEPROM on the printer and call the image by name. This is only viable if you are using it only once.  If you are constantly generating a new different image, then you are reliant on the transfer medium.